# Unable to load SWF from application storage directory

Tags: air, loader

While publishing my AIR application(CurrentFile), I have also included chatFile.swf with the installation files.
In my AIR settings panel [AIR 3.7 for Desktop], under 'Include Files' I have the following:

> - CurrentFile.swf
> - CurrentFile-app.xml
> - chatFile.swf

Here is the AS3 code in my CurrentFile.swf:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;    
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.filesystem.File;
var chatLoaderWindow:Loader;    
    function loadchat(m:MouseEvent):void
    {

        chatLoaderWindow = new Loader();
        chatLoaderWindow.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, chatLoadComplete);
        chatLoaderWindow.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, chatInitLoad);
        chatLoaderWindow.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, chatErrorLoad);
        chatLoaderWindow.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, chatHttpStatus);
        myclip.chatwindow.addChild(chatLoaderWindow);
        var f:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("chatFile.swf");
        chatLoaderWindow.load(new URLRequest(f.url));
        tracebox.text = "Chat URL" + f.url;
    }
    function chatLoadComplete(e:Event):void
    {
        tracebox.text = "chat loaded";

    }
    function chatErrorLoad(io:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        tracebox.text = "chat IO Error: "+io;

    }
    function chatInitLoad(i:Event):void
    {
        tracebox.text = "chat INIT";

    }
    function chatHttpStatus(e:HTTPStatusEvent):void
    {
        tracebox.text = "chat Http"+e;

    }
    myclip.chatbut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,loadchat);


    /*
    Output:
    chat IO Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2035" errorID=2035]
```

EDIT: I figured it out. It was really simple

This is not required:

```
var f:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("chatFile.swf");
chatLoaderWindow.load(new URLRequest(f.url));
```

Insert this:

```
chatLoaderWindow.load(new URLRequest("app:/chatFile.swf"));
```

So now my question is:
What is the purpose of File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath?

Answer (score 0):

There are two directories here. One is the "application" directory, where your install files are placed. One is the "application-storage" directory, which is a convenient place to write files to at runtime. To access these directories you can either use the File.resolvePath() function or use the URI-scheme shortcuts, app: or app-storage:. In your initial attempt, you were just looking in the wrong directory for your file.

Answer (score 0):

File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("somefile.swf").url will equal "app-storage:/somefile.swf"

File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("somefile.swf").url will equal "app:/somefile.swf"

The application directory is where your app was installed. The app storage directory is a folder your app can save files to.

resolvePath() returns a file object. You can use it for purposes other than getting the cross-platform url for the file location, such as fileObj.exists and fileObj.parent.createDirectory(). fileObj.url is just the url you would use with URLLoader to access the file in a platform-independent manner.